# Starting VirtualBox machines fails with "Unable to load R3 module ... VBoxDD.DLL (VBoxDD)"

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, dll

Starting any machine on VirtualBox 4.3.22 on Windows 7, is failing with the following errors:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Kivy.

Unable to load R3 module C:\Program Files\VirtualBox/VBoxDD.DLL (VBoxDD): GetLastError=1790 (VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

(BTW, I get the same errors on VirtualBox 4.3.20).

**The relevant (last) log lines are:**

```
00:00:17.740881 BlkCache: Cache successfully initialised. Cache size is 5242880 bytes
00:00:17.740898 BlkCache: Cache commit interval is 10000 ms
00:00:17.740906 BlkCache: Cache commit threshold is 2621440 bytes
00:00:18.565718 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-4.3\src\VBox\VMM\VMMR3\PDMLdr.cpp(307) int __cdecl pdmR3LoadR3U(struct UVM *,const char *,const char *); rc=VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR
00:00:18.565730 VMSetError: Unable to load R3 module C:\Program Files\VirtualBox/VBoxDD.DLL (VBoxDD): GetLastError=1790
00:00:18.567372 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_FAIL (0x80004005) aIID={8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6} aComponent={Console} aText={Unable to load R3 module C:\Program Files\VirtualBox/VBoxDD.DLL (VBoxDD): GetLastError=1790 (VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR)}, preserve=false
00:00:18.705525 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
00:00:18.728338 UIMachineView::storeGuestSizeHint: Storing guest size-hint for screen 0 as 640x480
00:00:18.748664 OpenGL Error: Render SPU: (MakeCurrent) failed to make 0x101173f, 0x10000 current with 0x6 error.
```

**The log is:**

```
VirtualBox VM 4.3.22 r98236 win.amd64 (Feb 12 2015 15:53:11) release log
00:00:06.331581 Log opened 2015-03-02T15:36:30.722578400Z
00:00:06.331583 Build Type: release
00:00:06.331588 OS Product: Windows 7
00:00:06.331591 OS Release: 6.1.7601
00:00:06.331593 OS Service Pack: 1
00:00:06.739357 DMI Product Name: Inspiron 3421
00:00:06.744936 DMI Product Version: Not Specified
00:00:06.744945 Host RAM: 8089MB total, 968MB available
00:00:06.744948 Executable: C:\Program Files\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
00:00:06.744949 Process ID: 13164
00:00:06.744951 Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:06.752599 Installed Extension Packs:
00:00:06.752653   None installed!
00:00:06.761934 UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration finished!
00:00:06.966946 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cached rc=VERR_LDRVI_NOT_SIGNED fImage=1 fProtect=0x0 fAccess=0x0 cHits=512 \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll
00:00:06.967284 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: rejecting 'C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll' (C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll): rcNt=0xc0000190
00:00:07.245504 SUP: Loaded VMMR0.r0 (C:\Program Files\VirtualBox\VMMR0.r0) at 0xfffff8802320b000 - ModuleInit at fffff8802322a6e0 and ModuleTerm at fffff8802322a9f0 using the native ring-0 loader
00:00:07.245536 SUP: VMMR0EntryEx located at fffff8802322bc20, VMMR0EntryFast at fffff8802322ad70 and VMMR0EntryInt at fffff8802322ad60
00:00:07.245544 SUP: windbg> .reload /f C:\Program Files\VirtualBox\VMMR0.r0=0xfffff8802320b000
00:00:07.252869 Guest OS type: 'Ubuntu'
00:00:07.287266 File system of 'C:\Users\Administrator\VirtualBox VMs\Kivy\Snapshots' (snapshots) is unknown
00:00:07.287280 File system of 'C:\tmp\incoming\Kivy_Python_for_android\Kivy_Python_for_android.vdi' is ntfs
00:00:07.384754 Shared clipboard mode: Off
00:00:07.451212 Drag'n'drop mode: Off
00:00:17.546349 OpenGL Info: Render SPU: GL_VENDOR:   Intel
00:00:17.546374 OpenGL Info: Render SPU: GL_RENDERER: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
00:00:17.546423 OpenGL Info: Render SPU: GL_VERSION:  4.0.0 - Build 9.17.10.2932
...
00:00:17.668054 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668057   Object <integer> = 0x000000000421ad00 (69 315 840)
00:00:17.668072 
00:00:17.668073 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668075   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cb=11)
00:00:17.668077 
00:00:17.668078 [/Devices/VMMDev/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668081   First   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668083   Last    <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668085   papLeds <integer> = 0x0000000004a68808 (78 022 664)
00:00:17.668088 
00:00:17.668089 [/Devices/acpi/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668091 
00:00:17.668092 [/Devices/acpi/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668095   PCIBusNo      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668097   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000007 (7)
00:00:17.668099   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668101   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668103 
00:00:17.668104 [/Devices/acpi/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668107   CpuHotPlug        <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668110   FdcEnabled        <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668112   HostBusPciAddress <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668114   HpetEnabled       <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668116   IOAPIC            <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668118   IocPciAddress     <integer> = 0x0000000000010000 (65 536)
00:00:17.668121   NumCPUs           <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668123   RamHoleSize       <integer> = 0x0000000020000000 (536 870 912, 512 MB)
00:00:17.668127   RamSize           <integer> = 0x0000000020000000 (536 870 912, 512 MB)
00:00:17.668131   Serial0IoPortBase <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668132   Serial0Irq        <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668134   Serial1IoPortBase <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668136   Serial1Irq        <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668138   ShowCpu           <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668140   ShowRtc           <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668142   SmcEnabled        <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668144 
00:00:17.668145 [/Devices/acpi/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668148   Driver <string>  = "ACPIHost" (cb=9)
00:00:17.668150 
00:00:17.668151 [/Devices/acpi/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668160 
00:00:17.668161 [/Devices/ahci/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668163 
00:00:17.668164 [/Devices/ahci/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668167   PCIBusNo      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668169   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x000000000000000d (13)
00:00:17.668171   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668173   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668175 
00:00:17.668176 [/Devices/ahci/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668179   Bootable  <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668180   PortCount <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668182 
00:00:17.668183 [/Devices/ahci/0/Config/Port0/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668186   Hotpluggable        <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668189   NonRotationalMedium <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668191 
00:00:17.668192 [/Devices/ahci/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668194   Driver <string>  = "Block" (cb=6)
00:00:17.668196 
00:00:17.668196 [/Devices/ahci/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668200   Driver <string>  = "VD" (cb=3)
00:00:17.668201 
00:00:17.668202 [/Devices/ahci/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/Config/] (level 6)
00:00:17.668206   BlockCache <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668207   Format     <string>  = "VDI" (cb=4)
00:00:17.668209   Path       <string>  = "C:\tmp\incoming\Kivy_Python_for_android\Kivy_Python_for_android.vdi" (cb=68)
00:00:17.668212   Type       <string>  = "HardDisk" (cb=9)
00:00:17.668213   UseNewIo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668216 
00:00:17.668216 [/Devices/ahci/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668219   Mountable <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668221   Type      <string>  = "HardDisk" (cb=9)
00:00:17.668223 
00:00:17.668224 [/Devices/ahci/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668227   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cb=11)
00:00:17.668229 
00:00:17.668229 [/Devices/ahci/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668233   DeviceInstance        <string>  = "ahci/0" (cb=7)
00:00:17.668235   First                 <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668237   Last                  <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668240   pConsole              <integer> = 0x0000000004a681f0 (78 021 104)
00:00:17.668243   papLeds               <integer> = 0x0000000004a68538 (78 021 944)
00:00:17.668246   pmapMediumAttachments <integer> = 0x0000000004a68820 (78 022 688)
00:00:17.668249 
00:00:17.668250 [/Devices/apic/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668252 
00:00:17.668253 [/Devices/apic/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668255   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668257 
00:00:17.668258 [/Devices/apic/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668261   IOAPIC  <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668263   NumCPUs <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668265 
00:00:17.668266 [/Devices/e1000/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668268 
00:00:17.668269 [/Devices/e1000/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668271   PCIBusNo      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668274   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000003 (3)
00:00:17.668276   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668278   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668280 
00:00:17.668280 [/Devices/e1000/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668283   AdapterType    <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668285   CableConnected <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668287   LineSpeed      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668289   MAC            <bytes>   = "08 00 27 22 35 2e" (cb=6)
00:00:17.668293 
00:00:17.668294 [/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668297   Driver <string>  = "NAT" (cb=4)
00:00:17.668298 
00:00:17.668299 [/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668303   AliasMode       <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668305   BootFile        <string>  = "Kivy.pxe" (cb=9)
00:00:17.668307   DNSProxy        <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668309   Network         <string>  = "10.0.2.0/24" (cb=12)
00:00:17.668311   PassDomain      <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668313   TFTPPrefix      <string>  = "C:\Users\Administrator/.VirtualBox\TFTP" (cb=40)
00:00:17.668315   UseHostResolver <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668317 
00:00:17.668318 [/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668321   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cb=11)
00:00:17.668322 
00:00:17.668323 [/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668326   First   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668328   Last    <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668330   papLeds <integer> = 0x0000000004a686e8 (78 022 376)
00:00:17.668333 
00:00:17.668333 [/Devices/i8254/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668336 
00:00:17.668337 [/Devices/i8254/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668339 
00:00:17.668340 [/Devices/i8254/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668342 
00:00:17.668343 [/Devices/i8259/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668345 
00:00:17.668346 [/Devices/i8259/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668348   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668350 
00:00:17.668351 [/Devices/i8259/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668354 
00:00:17.668355 [/Devices/ichac97/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668357 
00:00:17.668358 [/Devices/ichac97/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668360   PCIBusNo      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668362   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000005 (5)
00:00:17.668364   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668366   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668368 
00:00:17.668369 [/Devices/ichac97/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668372 
00:00:17.668373 [/Devices/ichac97/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668375   Driver <string>  = "AUDIO" (cb=6)
00:00:17.668377 
00:00:17.668378 [/Devices/ichac97/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668381   AudioDriver <string>  = "dsound" (cb=7)
00:00:17.668383   StreamName  <string>  = "Kivy" (cb=5)
00:00:17.668385 
00:00:17.668385 [/Devices/mc146818/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668388 
00:00:17.668389 [/Devices/mc146818/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668391 
00:00:17.668392 [/Devices/mc146818/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668395   UseUTC <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668397 
00:00:17.668398 [/Devices/parallel/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668400 
00:00:17.668401 [/Devices/pcarch/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668403 
00:00:17.668403 [/Devices/pcarch/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668406   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668408 
00:00:17.668408 [/Devices/pcarch/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668411 
00:00:17.668412 [/Devices/pcbios/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668414 
00:00:17.668415 [/Devices/pcbios/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668417   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668419 
00:00:17.668420 [/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668424   BootDevice0        <string>  = "FLOPPY" (cb=7)
00:00:17.668426   BootDevice1        <string>  = "DVD" (cb=4)
00:00:17.668427   BootDevice2        <string>  = "IDE" (cb=4)
00:00:17.668429   BootDevice3        <string>  = "NONE" (cb=5)
00:00:17.668431   FloppyDevice       <string>  = "i82078" (cb=7)
00:00:17.668432   HardDiskDevice     <string>  = "piix3ide" (cb=9)
00:00:17.668434   IOAPIC             <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668437   McfgBase           <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668439   McfgLength         <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668441   NumCPUs            <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668444   PXEDebug           <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668446   RamHoleSize        <integer> = 0x0000000020000000 (536 870 912, 512 MB)
00:00:17.668450   RamSize            <integer> = 0x0000000020000000 (536 870 912, 512 MB)
00:00:17.668454   SataHardDiskDevice <string>  = "ahci" (cb=5)
00:00:17.668455   SataLUN1           <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668458   UUID               <bytes>   = "cf cd 4d ed 50 f6 6d 46 8e 8e ca 4a b0 be 60 2f" (cb=16)
00:00:17.668465 
00:00:17.668465 [/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/NetBoot/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668469 
00:00:17.668469 [/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/NetBoot/0/] (level 6)
00:00:17.668473   NIC           <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668475   PCIBusNo      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668477   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000003 (3)
00:00:17.668479   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668481 
00:00:17.668482 [/Devices/pci/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668484 
00:00:17.668485 [/Devices/pci/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668487   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668489 
00:00:17.668490 [/Devices/pci/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668493   IOAPIC <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668495 
00:00:17.668495 [/Devices/pckbd/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668498 
00:00:17.668498 [/Devices/pckbd/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668501   Trusted <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668503 
00:00:17.668504 [/Devices/pckbd/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668506 
00:00:17.668507 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668510   Driver <string>  = "KeyboardQueue" (cb=14)
00:00:17.668512 
00:00:17.668513 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668516   Driver <string>  = "MainKeyboard" (cb=13)
00:00:17.668517 
00:00:17.668518 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/Config/] (level 6)
00:00:17.668522   Object <integer> = 0x0000000004304f70 (70 274 928)
00:00:17.668524 
00:00:17.668525 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668528   QueueSize <integer> = 0x0000000000000040 (64)
00:00:17.668531 
00:00:17.668531 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#1/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668534   Driver <string>  = "MouseQueue" (cb=11)
00:00:17.668536 
00:00:17.668536 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#1/AttachedDriver/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668539   Driver <string>  = "MainMouse" (cb=10)
00:00:17.668541 
00:00:17.668542 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#1/AttachedDriver/Config/] (level 6)
00:00:17.668545   Object <integer> = 0x0000000004a23180 (77 738 368)
00:00:17.668548 
00:00:17.668548 [/Devices/pckbd/0/LUN#1/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668551   QueueSize <integer> = 0x0000000000000080 (128)
00:00:17.668554 
00:00:17.668554 [/Devices/pcnet/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668556 
00:00:17.668557 [/Devices/piix3ide/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668559 
00:00:17.668560 [/Devices/piix3ide/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668563   PCIBusNo      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668565   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668567   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668569   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668571 
00:00:17.668572 [/Devices/piix3ide/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668575   Type <string>  = "PIIX4" (cb=6)
00:00:17.668576 
00:00:17.668577 [/Devices/piix3ide/0/Config/SecondaryMaster/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668581   NonRotationalMedium <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668583 
00:00:17.668583 [/Devices/piix3ide/0/LUN#2/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668586   Driver <string>  = "Block" (cb=6)
00:00:17.668588 
00:00:17.668588 [/Devices/piix3ide/0/LUN#2/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668592   Mountable <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668594   Type      <string>  = "DVD" (cb=4)
00:00:17.668596 
00:00:17.668596 [/Devices/piix3ide/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668599   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cb=11)
00:00:17.668601 
00:00:17.668602 [/Devices/piix3ide/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668605   DeviceInstance        <string>  = "piix3ide/0" (cb=11)
00:00:17.668607   First                 <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668610   Last                  <integer> = 0x0000000000000003 (3)
00:00:17.668612   pConsole              <integer> = 0x0000000004a681f0 (78 021 104)
00:00:17.668615   papLeds               <integer> = 0x0000000004a68518 (78 021 912)
00:00:17.668619   pmapMediumAttachments <integer> = 0x0000000004a68820 (78 022 688)
00:00:17.668621 
00:00:17.668622 [/Devices/serial/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668624 
00:00:17.668625 [/Devices/usb-ohci/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668627 
00:00:17.668628 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668630   PCIBusNo      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668632   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000006 (6)
00:00:17.668634   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668636   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668638 
00:00:17.668652 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668655 
00:00:17.668655 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668658   Driver <string>  = "VUSBRootHub" (cb=12)
00:00:17.668659 
00:00:17.668660 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668663 
00:00:17.668664 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/LUN#999/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668667   Driver <string>  = "MainStatus" (cb=11)
00:00:17.668668 
00:00:17.668669 [/Devices/usb-ohci/0/LUN#999/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668672   First   <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668674   Last    <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668676   papLeds <integer> = 0x0000000004a68810 (78 022 672)
00:00:17.668679 
00:00:17.668679 [/Devices/vga/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668682 
00:00:17.668682 [/Devices/vga/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668685   PCIBusNo      <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668687   PCIDeviceNo   <integer> = 0x0000000000000002 (2)
00:00:17.668689   PCIFunctionNo <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668691   Trusted       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668693 
00:00:17.668694 [/Devices/vga/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668697   CustomVideoModes <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668699   FadeIn           <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668701   FadeOut          <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668703   HeightReduction  <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668705   LogoFile         <string>  = "" (cb=1)
00:00:17.668707   LogoTime         <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668709   MonitorCount     <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668711   ShowBootMenu     <integer> = 0x0000000000000002 (2)
00:00:17.668713   VRamSize         <integer> = 0x0000000002000000 (33 554 432, 32 MB)
00:00:17.668716 
00:00:17.668717 [/Devices/vga/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668720   Driver <string>  = "MainDisplay" (cb=12)
00:00:17.668721 
00:00:17.668722 [/Devices/vga/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668725   Object <integer> = 0x0000000004a6ccd0 (78 040 272)
00:00:17.668727 
00:00:17.668728 [/Devices/virtio-net/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668731 
00:00:17.668732 [/EM/] (level 1)
00:00:17.668734   TripleFaultReset <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668736 
00:00:17.668737 [/HM/] (level 1)
00:00:17.668739   64bitEnabled       <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668741   EnableLargePages   <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668743   EnableNestedPaging <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668745   EnableUX           <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668747   EnableVPID         <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:17.668749   Exclusive          <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668751   HMForced           <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668754 
00:00:17.668754 [/MM/] (level 1)
00:00:17.668756   CanUseLargerHeap <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668758 
00:00:17.668759 [/PDM/] (level 1)
00:00:17.668761 
00:00:17.668762 [/PDM/AsyncCompletion/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668764 
00:00:17.668765 [/PDM/AsyncCompletion/File/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668768 
00:00:17.668768 [/PDM/AsyncCompletion/File/BwGroups/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668772 
00:00:17.668772 [/PDM/BlkCache/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668775   CacheSize <integer> = 0x0000000000500000 (5 242 880, 5 MB)
00:00:17.668778 
00:00:17.668779 [/PDM/Devices/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668781 
00:00:17.668782 [/PDM/Drivers/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668784 
00:00:17.668785 [/PDM/Drivers/VBoxC/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668787   Path <string>  = "VBoxC" (cb=6)
00:00:17.668789 
00:00:17.668790 [/PDM/NetworkShaper/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668792 
00:00:17.668793 [/PDM/NetworkShaper/BwGroups/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668795 
00:00:17.668796 [/TM/] (level 1)
00:00:17.668798   UTCOffset <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:17.668800 
00:00:17.668801 [/USB/] (level 1)
00:00:17.668802 
00:00:17.668803 [/USB/HidMouse/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668805 
00:00:17.668806 [/USB/HidMouse/0/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668808 
00:00:17.668809 [/USB/HidMouse/0/Config/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668812   Mode <string>  = "absolute" (cb=9)
00:00:17.668813 
00:00:17.668814 [/USB/HidMouse/0/LUN#0/] (level 4)
00:00:17.668817   Driver <string>  = "MouseQueue" (cb=11)
00:00:17.668818 
00:00:17.668819 [/USB/HidMouse/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668823   Driver <string>  = "MainMouse" (cb=10)
00:00:17.668824 
00:00:17.668825 [/USB/HidMouse/0/LUN#0/AttachedDriver/Config/] (level 6)
00:00:17.668828   Object <integer> = 0x0000000004a23180 (77 738 368)
00:00:17.668831 
00:00:17.668831 [/USB/HidMouse/0/LUN#0/Config/] (level 5)
00:00:17.668834   QueueSize <integer> = 0x0000000000000080 (128)
00:00:17.668837 
00:00:17.668837 [/USB/USBProxy/] (level 2)
00:00:17.668839 
00:00:17.668840 [/USB/USBProxy/GlobalConfig/] (level 3)
00:00:17.668843 
00:00:17.668844 ********************* End of CFGM dump **********************
00:00:17.668860 VM: fHMEnabled=true  (configured) fRecompileUser=false fRecompileSupervisor=false
00:00:17.668863 VM: fRawRing1Enabled=false CSAM=true  PATM=true 
00:00:17.669294 HMR3Init: VT-x w/ nested paging
00:00:17.669538 MM: cbHyperHeap=0x100000 (1048576)
00:00:17.674666 CPUM: Matched host CPU INTEL 0x6/0x3a/0x9 Intel_Core7_IvyBridge with CPU DB entry 'Intel Core i5-3570' (INTEL 0x6/0x3a/0x9 Intel_Core7_IvyBridge).
00:00:17.675240 CPUM: SetGuestCpuIdFeature: Enabled PAE
00:00:17.678560 Debug: HCPhysInterPD=00000000c6c05000 HCPhysInterPaePDPT=00000000c6c02000 HCPhysInterPaePML4=00000000c6c00000
00:00:17.678586 Debug: apInterPTs={00000000c6c04000,00000000c6c03000} apInterPaePTs={00000000c1dbd000,00000001d6f3e000} apInterPaePDs={000000016a847000,0000000084b80000,000000019e441000,0000000054102000} pInterPaePDPT64=00000000c6c01000
00:00:17.678603 Host paging mode: AMD64+PGE+NX
00:00:17.678696 PGMPool: cMaxPages=288 (u64MaxPages=288)
00:00:17.678709 pgmR3PoolInit: cMaxPages=0x120 cMaxUsers=0x240 cMaxPhysExts=0x240 fCacheEnable=true 
00:00:17.705138 TM: GIP - u32Mode=1 (SyncTSC) u32UpdateHz=100
00:00:17.737339 TM: cTSCTicksPerSecond=0x6b0e1b48 (1 796 086 600) fTSCVirtualized=true  fTSCUseRealTSC=false
00:00:17.737348 TM: fMaybeUseOffsettedHostTSC=true  TSCTiedToExecution=false TSCNotTiedToHalt=false
00:00:17.739506 CoreCode: R3=0000000000470000 R0=fffff8800e198000 RC=a0349000 Phys=00000000c6b8f000 cb=0x1000
00:00:17.740446 AIOMgr: Default manager type is "Async"
00:00:17.740460 AIOMgr: Default file backend is "NonBuffered"
00:00:17.740881 BlkCache: Cache successfully initialised. Cache size is 5242880 bytes
00:00:17.740898 BlkCache: Cache commit interval is 10000 ms
00:00:17.740906 BlkCache: Cache commit threshold is 2621440 bytes
00:00:18.565718 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-4.3\src\VBox\VMM\VMMR3\PDMLdr.cpp(307) int __cdecl pdmR3LoadR3U(struct UVM *,const char *,const char *); rc=VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR
00:00:18.565730 VMSetError: Unable to load R3 module C:\Program Files\VirtualBox/VBoxDD.DLL (VBoxDD): GetLastError=1790
00:00:18.567372 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_FAIL (0x80004005) aIID={8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6} aComponent={Console} aText={Unable to load R3 module C:\Program Files\VirtualBox/VBoxDD.DLL (VBoxDD): GetLastError=1790 (VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR)}, preserve=false
00:00:18.705525 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
00:00:18.728338 UIMachineView::storeGuestSizeHint: Storing guest size-hint for screen 0 as 640x480
00:00:18.748664 OpenGL Error: Render SPU: (MakeCurrent) failed to make 0x101173f, 0x10000 current with 0x6 error.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtual box is not working on windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1391838/virtual-box-is-not-working-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a known VB bug

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13504?cversion=1&cnum_hist=1

Comment: Thanks @Pat: with the installation of 4.3.12, my VirtualBox machines are indeed able to start. (Shame that Google robots are not mining the data inside virtualbox.org).

Answer (score 3):

Obviously your system file `uxtheme.dll` is patched to support 3-rd party themes.

Restoring the original file will solve this problem.