# Error when starting VirtualBox (Unable to load R3 module)

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm aware [this question has already been asked](https://superuser.com/questions/884575/starting-virtualbox-machines-fails-with-unable-to-load-r3-module-vboxdd-dll), but the answer points to a website that is currently down and is relevant to a VirtualBox version that's old and irrelevant to my version/problem. I'm running VirtualBox 4.3.28 on Windows 8.1 (all sys spec requirements are met), and when I try to start a new virtual machine I get the error: `Unable to load R3 module C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VBoxDD.DLL (VBoxDD): GetLastError=1790 (VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR)` >Details show:

```
Result Code:     E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component:       Console
Interface:       IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6
```

The error log shows:

```
00:00:03.062560 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-4.3\src\VBox\VMM\VMMR3\PDMLdr.cpp(307) int __cdecl pdmR3LoadR3U(struct UVM *,const char *,const char *); rc=VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR
00:00:03.062567 VMSetError: Unable to load R3 module C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VBoxDD.DLL (VBoxDD): GetLastError=1790
00:00:03.064344 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_FAIL (0x80004005) aIID={8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6} aComponent={Console} aText={Unable to load R3 module C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VBoxDD.DLL (VBoxDD): GetLastError=1790 (VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR)}, preserve=false
00:00:03.209271 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
00:00:03.215623 UIMachineView::storeGuestSizeHint: Storing guest size-hint for screen 0 as 640x480
00:00:03.240351 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cached rc=VERR_LDRVI_NOT_SIGNED fImage=1 fProtect=0x0 fAccess=0x0 cHits=512 \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll
00:00:03.240443 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: rejecting 'C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll' (C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll): rcNt=0xc0000190
00:00:03.251734 OpenGL Error: Render SPU: (MakeCurrent) failed to make 0x4f011131, 0x10000 current with 0x6 error.
```

I don't know how much of that is relevant as I'm a total VirtualBox noob. Like, a complete noob, but any help would be appreciated.

Also, I've done a ton of googling but everything I found either didn't work or the site was down (VirtualBox's site is currently "down for maintenace" and has been for the past 24 hours).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtual box is not working on windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1391838/virtual-box-is-not-working-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution to my problem but not an answer to my question. Throughout my research I picked up on vague references to version/patch bugs so I downgraded. Downgrading seems to work.