# Virtual box is not working on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bios, virtualization

I have installed virtual box But when I tried to run it. It shows me an error as:

[image]

I have been trying everything for whole day. Like there are answers related to this question as:

[VT-x is not available, but is enabled in BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/1153470/vt-x-is-not-available-but-is-enabled-in-bios)
[VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX) (VirtualBox) but enabled in bios, hyper-v enabled, and cpu supported](https://superuser.com/questions/1383262/vt-x-is-not-available-verr-vmx-no-vmx-virtualbox-but-enabled-in-bios-hyper)

But nothing seems to work out in my case. I want to install ubuntu18.04 on VM.

These are my logs:

```
00:00:02.822701 VirtualBox VM 6.0.0 r127566 win.amd64 (Dec 18 2018 12:01:23) release log
00:00:02.822732 Log opened 2019-01-08T10:02:05.773237700Z
00:00:02.822733 Build Type: release
00:00:02.822737 OS Product: Windows 10
00:00:02.822738 OS Release: 10.0.17134
00:00:02.822739 OS Service Pack: 
00:00:02.902704 DMI Product Name: 20L6S4T80H
00:00:02.907611 DMI Product Version: ThinkPad T480
00:00:02.907624 Host RAM: 16262MB (15.8GB) total, 11912MB (11.6GB) available
00:00:02.907627 Executable: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
00:00:02.907627 Process ID: 12160
00:00:02.907628 Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:02.909800 Installed Extension Packs:
00:00:02.909899   None installed!
00:00:02.911165 Console: Machine state changed to 'Starting'
00:00:02.911757 Qt version: 5.6.2
00:00:02.915484 GUI: UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration finished!
00:00:03.057646 SUP: Loaded VMMR0.r0 (C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VMMR0.r0) at 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - ModuleInit at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and ModuleTerm at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX using the native ring-0 loader
00:00:03.057680 SUP: VMMR0EntryEx located at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and VMMR0EntryFast at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
00:00:03.057687 SUP: windbg> .reload /f C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VMMR0.r0=0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
00:00:03.062104 Guest OS type: 'Ubuntu_64'
00:00:03.064007 fHMForced=true - Lots of RAM
00:00:03.064022 fHMForced=true - 64-bit guest
00:00:03.070587 File system of 'C:\Users\hichaudh\Downloads\ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso' (DVD) is ntfs
00:00:03.075516 File system of 'C:\Users\hichaudh\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu\Snapshots' (snapshots) is unknown
00:00:03.075531 File system of 'C:\Users\hichaudh\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu\Ubuntu.vdi' is ntfs
00:00:03.112825 Shared clipboard service loaded
00:00:03.112847 Shared clipboard mode: Off
00:00:03.137749 Drag and drop service loaded
00:00:03.137761 Drag and drop mode: Off
00:00:03.139869 ************************* CFGM dump *************************
00:00:03.255048 NEM:                             ShaSupport: 0
00:00:03.255052 NEM:                X87PointersSavedSupport: 0
00:00:03.255089 NEM: WHvCapabilityCodeProcessorClFlushSize = 2^8
00:00:03.256588 NEM: VidGetHvPartitionId            -> fun:0x2210a3 in:0x0 out:0x8
00:00:03.256618 NEM: VidStartVirtualProcessor       -> fun:0x22115c in:0x4 out:0x0
00:00:03.256623 NEM: VidStopVirtualProcessor        -> fun:0x221168 in:0x4 out:0x0
00:00:03.256635 NEM: VidMessageSlotHandleAndGetNext -> fun:0x2210cb in:0xc out:0x0
00:00:03.256722 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-rel\src\VBox\VMM\VMMR3\NEMR3Native-win.cpp(1298) int __cdecl nemR3NativeInit(struct VM *,bool,bool); rc=VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API
00:00:03.256907 VMSetError: 
00:00:03.256936 NEM: NEMR3Init: Native init failed: VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API.
00:00:03.256946 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-rel\src\VBox\VMM\VMMR3\HM.cpp(818) int __cdecl HMR3Init(struct VM *); rc=VERR_VMX_NO_VMX
00:00:03.256974 VMSetError: VT-x is not available
00:00:03.258928 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_FAIL (0x80004005) aIID={872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} aComponent={ConsoleWrap} aText={ (VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API).
00:00:03.259018 VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-4009
00:00:03.259562 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
00:00:03.266129 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_VMX_NO_VMX, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
00:00:03.767441 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::resendSizeHint: Restoring guest size-hint for screen 0 to 800x600
00:00:03.767486 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={ab4164db-c13e-4dab-842d-61ee3f0c1e87} aComponent={DisplayWrap} aText={The console is not powered up}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:03.767731 GUI: Aborting startup due to power up progress issue detected...
```

**Note:**

- I have checked my BIOS VT-x is enabled.
- Hyper-V is disabled from windows features.
- Windows virtualization is enabled from windows features.

Any help !

Comment: What CPU do you have?

Comment: @Seth it is intel i5.  `Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8350U CPU @ 1.70GHz, 1896 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)`

Comment: Related: [VirtualBox on Windows 10 64bit doesn't have a 64bit option](https://superuser.com/questions/1211629/virtualbox-on-windows-10-64bit-doesnt-have-a-64bit-option/1366359#1366359)

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/a/1374706/313666

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have figured it out after giving my whole Day. There are other settings too in windows which needs to be figured out when working with VM. We need to `disable` Windows Hypervisor Platform and Virtual Machine Platform along with Hyper-V.

[image]

Since I have installed docker desktop on windows due to which these setting are enabled. Also you need to restart after changing these settings.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be enough as of 1909, I had to [completely disable Hyper-V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496116/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-command-line), which involves more steps

Comment: In my case Windows Hypervisor Platform and Virtual Machine Platform were already off, so it was disabling Hyper-V that did the trick. I've noticed many differences in the failed vs successful VBox.log. At the end of my failed log (blinking cursor in the VM), I could see a few repetitions of "00:05:17.960169 TM: Giving up catch-up attempt at a 60 004 184 974 ns lag; new total: 180 013 257 064 ns".

Answer (score 28):

from windows features, I disabled a number of features, retrying each time. I disabled the following:

- Hyper-V
- Virtual Machine Platform
- Windows Hypervisor platform
- Container

Hope that helps someone

Comment: Thanks! It was the `Container` option that did it for me :).

Comment: For me it was Virtual Hyper Platform

Comment: I also needed to run this in admin command prompt: `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

Comment: it's "Containers", not "Container"

Comment: Per [this thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=96201), after `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`, I also did `shutdown -s -t 2`. Then, after my computer shutdown, I unplugged it for a minute. Insanity that somehow worked ergh.

Comment: For me it worked disabling "Virtual Machine Platform"

Answer (score 4):

I have similar problem. Then I found it out that Windows Defender Application Guard also needs to be disabled and then my VM runs well.

Comment: And don't forget to restart with `shutdown -r -t 0`, normal reboot does not work.

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed to get my VirtualBox **back up**  and running, too.  With me, the thing was, that it *was running* at some point earlier, since I have the image and user set up in the VirtualBox already..
.. but in the meantime, *some Windows update and/or Windows security update* must have changed something and I could no longer start the virtual machine.

So to summarize, I have done every single thing that was already posted in this thread, i.e. :
*I disabled the following:*

- Hyper-V *(certainly needs to be off)*
- Virtual Machine Platform
- Windows Hypervisor platform *([not certain](https://superuser.com/questions/1510172/hyper-v-vs-virtual-machine-platform-vs-windows-hypervisor-platform-settings-in-p) if needs to be off)*
- Containers

I have been to the BIOS and verified VT-x is **enabled** somewhere in the "Virtualization". While **you** are there, **disable** anything that looks like Memory Protection, too!

But the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1391838/virtual-box-is-not-working-on-windows-10/1406396#1406396) led me to Windows Defender/Antivirus..

> Settings->Application Guard, *leads you to **"App & Browser Control"***

Go to:

> **"App & Browser Control"** -> Exploit Protection -> **Exploit Protection Settings** -> Data Execution Prevention (DEP) = "Off by default"

➡ asks you for restart, then after the restart, **VirtualBox finally worked**.

What is interesting is that after this was done I went to *Exploit Protection* again but the DEP was back to "Use default (On)".  I am wondering if there was some driver/feature that was incorrectly installed in the previous (six?) times I have restarted and now it finally got configured correctly..

You might also need to check/disable this (I have done it earlier):

> Windows Security-> Device Security -> Core isolation -> Memory integrity = off.

The [Intel® Processor Identification Utility](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28539/Intel-Processor-Identification-Utility-Windows-Version) helped for all of this. You start it and you need it show this for VT-x:

[image: list of cpu technologies]

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me and finally got run my VM.