# Failed to use a virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

I have a problem. This same error happended to me on a Lenovo B590 Laptop. The error code is Failed to open a session for the virtual machine WinXp.

Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROhJq.jpg   Image used for answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtual box is not working on windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1391838/virtual-box-is-not-working-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

The CPU feature VT-x is needed for VirtualBox.  This typically needs to be explicitly enabled in your BIOS (probably named something along "Virtualization")

You may also have to disable Hyper-V in Windows.

Comment: To be more precise, VT-x needs to be enabled and no other VM can be active, if you want to start an x64 machine. x86 machines will still work.

Comment: Downvoted even.  Interesting.

Comment: Not by me though...

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable virtualisation in your bios settings. Kindly run your bois by pressing F10 or delete key depending upto your system type and than over their in advanced settings you will find virtualisation option and you should enable it and run virtual machine again.