# VirtualBox: Ubuntu instance fails to start with error

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I get the below error when trying to start up my Ubuntu instance on VB in my Windows 10 env.

VMMR0_DO_NEM_INIT_VM failed: VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API_2 (VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API_2). VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005) Component: ConsoleWrap Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

From googling, ive turned off Virtualisation in my laptop but still get this error, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Turning Virtualisation off is not the answer here. That's what the `VT-x is not available` error you are getting there is complaining about.

Since there isn't one specific way to fix this, aside from just *having* the right configuration. I would suggest you go through this with a systematic approach:

- Uninstall VirtualBox.
- Turn **off** Hyper-V if it is enabled. While the two can co-exist, you will get much better performance from VirtualBox if Hyper-V is disabled.

  - You can turn off Hyper-V from the **Turn Windows features on and off** settings menu.
- Enabled VT-x (Virtualisation) in your BIOS.
- Reinstall VirtualBox.
- Reinstall your desired guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

Also disable Windows Hypervisor Platform , as it needs to be disabled along with Hyper-V itself. See if that works for you.

[Virtual box is not working on windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1391838/virtual-box-is-not-working-on-windows-10)

Comment: Looks like your linked question is an appropriate target to VTC this question as a duplicate.